# Error: Can't Assign Function Call / Don't want to

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, function

It's friday and I'm tired and my brain obvs doesn't want to find this answer. Please help.

I want to assign the value to an array. It works in subsequent lines but not in one particular line, even though syntax seems the same to me? It seems to think I'm calling a function??

> ```
>   for entry in PROJECT:
>                     i = i + 1
>     #A
>         if entry.startswith("A") :
>             ProjectA(i) = entry
>         #B
>         elif entry.startswith("B"):
>             ProjectB(i)= entry
>         #C
>         elif entry.startswith("C") :
>             ProjectC(i) = entry
>         # and Programme 
>         elif entry.startswith("D") :
>             ProjectD(i) = entry
> ```

I'm told the problem is the last line: "ProjectD(i) = entry". Which to me seems like a replica of "ProjectC(i) = entry"

Comment: That doesn't mean that `ProjectC(i) = entry` is correct, either.

Comment: but as I'm running the debugger and it's coming up with ProjectD being and issue and not ProjectC, it mean's it's checked it and it's "ok as far as debugging goes" ?

Comment: I'm gonna guess that's because `entry` starts with a `D`, so it never tries to execute the other versions.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ProjectA(i)` looks like you are calling a function; `ProjectA[i]` looks like an array element.